# Seg Fault, possible array pointer issue (Radix Sort Implementation)

Tags: c, algorithm, segmentation-fault

I am attempting to do a Radix sort on an array of "random" integers. The radix_sort function is giving me seg fault errors. I checked each for loop and none of them seem to go out of bounds so my assumption is that the problem may be the array pointers but I couldn't seem to find any source information on the web that helped with any such issue.
Compiled with GCC with -std=c99 flag

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define LEN 1000
#define BYTES 4
#define BINS 256

void create_lst();
void int_radix_sort();
void radix_sort(int);

long data[LEN];
long temp[LEN];

int main(int argc, char * * argv) {
  create_lst();
  int_radix_sort();

  return 0;
}
void create_lst() {
  for (int i = 0; i < LEN; i++) {
    srand(rand());
    data[i] = rand();
  }
  return;
}
void int_radix_sort() {
  for (int i = 0; i < BYTES; i++) {
    radix_sort(i);
  }
  return;
}
void radix_sort(int byte) {
  long map[BINS], count[BINS];
  long *src_p, *dst_p;

  if((byte%2) == 0){
    src_p = data;
    dst_p = temp; 
  } else {
    src_p = temp;
    dst_p = data;
  }
  // Count
  for(int i = 0; i < LEN; i++)
    count[(src_p[i] >> (byte*8)) & (BINS-1)]++;
  // Map
  map[0]=0;
  for(int j = 1; j < BINS; j++)
    map[j] = count[j-1] + count[j-1];
  // Move
  for(int k = 0; k < LEN; k++)
    dst_p[map[(src_p[k] >> (byte*8)) & (BINS-1)]++] = src_p[k];
  return;
}
```

Edit: More info - When I ran the program through a debugger I found the issue was on the last loop (with K variable)

Comment: What did your debugger tell you was going wrong?

Comment: `srand(rand())` isn't going to seed your random number generator usefully.

Comment: When I ran the program through a debugger I found the issue was on the last loop (with K variable)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for(int j = 1; j < BINS; j++)
    map[j] = count[j-1] + count[j-1];
```

is wrong. You want `map[j]` to hold the cumulative number of elements in the previous slots, so that ought to be

```
for(int j = 1; j < BINS; j++)
    map[j] = map[j-1] + count[j-1];
         //  ^^^
         //  add the number of items in bin j-1 to the number of items in previous bins
```

Comment: Thank you, that was such a silly error. Sometimes you need a second pair of eyes looking at a code(or maybe some more time in the debugger).

Answer (score 3):

The `count` array in `radix_sort` is uninitialized and its values are used for creating values in `map`, which in the end (see `// Move`) is used to index `dst_p` and then it is BOOM.

After your fix to initialize them, you end up with `1954` in `map[1]`, which is too big for `dst_p`, so now you are looking at an algorithmic problem. Try to add some tracing print statements to tackle your problem. Or go into a debugger (`gdb` on Linux) and step through your program to verify that all steps are as expected.

Comment: I just tried changing the initialization of count and map to "long map[BINS] = {0}, count[BINS] = {0};" but it still is giving me seg faults, am I doing it incorrectly?